# Pdfbox: how to merge two acroforms?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to use PDFBox 2.0.14 to merge two pdf documents which contain an acroform each.
If I use the method `PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments()` I get a merged document with two distinct acroform. While I would like to have a single acroform. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *"two distinct acroform"*? A pdf can by definition only host a single **AcroForm** structure.

Comment: I use pdfbox 2.0.14

Comment: `PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments()` *does* merge the two acroform structures. Maybe tell what you expected and what happened instead, and share the two PDF files.